# How do I query for the existance of a property without knowing its path

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to query cosmos DB for the existence of a property within a document without knowing where exactly this property is located as it might appear in different locations?

Basically

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeCollection
WHERE IS_DEFINED("here should be just the prop name w/o any path")
```

**Edit:**
I initially missed to state that I was looking for a solution on the query level instead of writing a user defined stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

you can create UDF which will recursively navigate though all object properties and return true if found on any level. In your case udf body can look similar to this

```
function findRecursive(theObject, searchingProperty){

    var result = null;
    if(theObject instanceof Array) {
        for(var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {
            if (findRecursive(theObject[i]){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(var prop in theObject) {
            if(prop == searchingProperty) {
                return true;
            }
            if(theObject[prop] instanceof Object || theObject[prop] instanceof Array){
                if (findRecursive(theObject[prop])){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

UDF should be register same as stored procedures. And can be called from queries.
So your select will look like next

```
SELECT * 
FROM root
WHERE udf.findRecursive(root, "here should be just the prop name w/o any path")
```

P.S. I didn't test the code, but you should get the basic idea